# How do I get my Android Room database to re-populate?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room

So here's my code for AppDatabase. I started with just `ChatUser` and `ChatMessage` as entities which worked just fine, but then I wanted to add `Well`s. I got it all sorted out and added them into this class, along with the 2 lines in the callback pre-initializing the database. The problem is that this will not work. The database does not pre-initialize even if I change the version number or uninstall the app. It was the first version when it was working, so I haven't been able to successfully iterate on the database. Please help!

```
@Database(entities = {ChatUser.class, ChatMessage.class, Well.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract UserDao userDao();

    public abstract MessageDao messageDao();

    public abstract WellDao wellDao();

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(final Context context) {
        Log.d("AppDatabase", "getting app database");
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "curadite-database")
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .addCallback(new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                                    super.onCreate(db);
                                    Log.d("AppDatabase", "OnCreate");
                                    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            ChatUser user = new ChatUser("Me", true);
                                            ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage("Hello!", 1, System.currentTimeMillis());
                                            AppDatabase db = getAppDatabase(context);
                                            db.userDao().insertAll(user);
                                            db.messageDao().insertAll(message);
                                            Well[] wells = new Curapac(7, 2).flatWells();
                                            db.wellDao().insertAll(wells);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            })
                            .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Callback` approach, using a thread to have your initialization occur at some unknowable time in the future, is not going to be very reliable. There is no requirement that your initialization work be completed by the time the caller of `getAppDatabase()` wants to use it.

Either:

- Use the supplied `SupportSQLiteDatabase` synchronously inside of `onCreate()` to populate your database, or
- Populate your database after the call to `build()` and before you exit the `if` block in your `getAppDatabase()` method, examining the current database contents to see if you need to perform the initialization

Also, your overall approach to managing this singleton will not handle simultaneous calls to `getAppDatabase()` very well. Please mark `INSTANCE` as `volatile` and mark `getAppDatabase()` as `synchronized`.

Comment: Or annotate `getAppDatabase()` with [`@MainThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/MainThread), if that's the intention.

Comment: @TKK That does not provide any synchronization. Also, you do not want to do database I/O on the main application thread.

Comment: In that case it should probably be annotated `@WorkerThread`. Making it `synchronized` would be sufficient; no need for `volatile`.